# How does /dev work in Docker?

Tags: docker

I had some issues with `/dev/random` and I replaced it with `/dev/urandom` on some of my servers:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jul 22 21:04 /dev/random -> /dev/urandom
```

I since have replaced some of my infrastructure with Docker. I thought, it would be sufficient to replace `/dev/random` on my host machine. But when starting the service, I quickly noticed that some RNG operations blocked because it used the original implementation of `/dev/random`.

I wrote a little test program to proof this behavior:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    f, err := os.Open("/dev/random")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    chunk := make([]byte, 1024)
    index := 0
    for {
        index = index + 1
        _, err := f.Read(chunk)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("iteration ", index)
    }
}
```

Executing this program on the host machine (which has the symlink) works as expected - it will not block and run until I shut it down.

When running this in a container, it will block after the first iteration (at least on my machine).

I can obviously fix this problem by mounting my random file into the container:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /dev/random:/dev/random bla
```

But this is not the point of this question. I want to know, the following:

- How does Docker set up the devices listed in /dev
- Why is it not just using (some) of the device files of the host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker never uses any of the host system's filesystem unless you explicitly instruct it to.  The device files in `/dev` are whatever (if anything) is baked into the image.

Also note that the conventional Unix device model is that a device "file" is either a character- or block-special device, and a pair of major and minor device numbers, and any actual handling is done in the kernel.  Relatedly, the host's kernel is shared across all Docker containers.  So if you fix your host's broken implementation of `/dev/random` then your containers will inherit this fix too; but merely changing what's in the host's `/dev` will have no effect.